# How the iPhone multi-touch event triggered?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, multi-touch

I read the SDK document, but can not understand some details, need some help.

for the

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
```

1. what's the difference between `touches` and `[event allTouches]`?
2. if user release one finger, but still has other fingers on screen, does the later event still contains the finger in `touches` or `[event allTouches]`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Touches set should represent just those touches that are relevant to the current call. For touches ended, the touches parameter will contain JUST the touch that ended, whereas the [UIEvent allTouches] array will contain all touches currently in progress, *including* the one that just ended.